# How to access session in an static object

Tags: php, symfony1, symfony-1.4

doees anybody knows, how to access session in an static object?

I am coding a cart right know and I have an class in lib/Cart.php

```
class cart {

public function calculatesum (){
$cart = $this->getUser()->getAttribute('cart');
}

}
```

This doesn't work. Anybody an idea?

Thanks!

Craphunter

Comment: are you using some lib that changes it? TRy $_SESSION['cart']

Comment: you are returing nothing from the function ??

Comment: it is a demo code because of that i don't return anything

Comment: I would pass the session id to the cart class from whatever action you are accessing cart from. It doesn't seem like good organization to try and handle the session directly from the cart class.

Answer (score 4):

You should inject the current user instance into the function.

```
class cart {

  public function calculatesum (myUser $user){
    $cart = $user->getAttribute('cart');
  }

}
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't get this: (myUser $user)

What is "myUser"? Where do I code it?

Comment: That's how you force the type of a passed parameter in php. myUser is the session class in symfony (found in apps/appname/lib/myUser.class.php).

Comment: Thanks, so how does this funktion look like? Like $user = $this->get->User(); in myUser.class.php?

And I can I pass this function in the template when I call calculatesum?

Comment: Inside myUser you can simply use $this->getAttribute() and such. Inside the template you can do it like $cart->calculatesum($sf_user).

Answer (score 0):

To access session variables, you first have to use

```
session_start();
```

Then after which you can do things like

```
$cart = $_SESSION['cart'];
```

in which i'm assuming you have stored your cart as a session variable beforehand

Comment: This is symfony and it is an framework, because of that it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

here it is, how you can access data from a session in a static function in symfony 1.4. Thanks again to Maerlyn!

In the /lib/Cart.php:

```
class cart {

public function calculatesum ($user){
$cart = $this->getUser()->getAttribute('cart');
}

}
```

In the template:

```
echo CAERT::calculatesum($sf_user);
```

Take a special look to $user and $sf_user.

Greetings!

Craphunter